# how to populate a document link on selecting a value in SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, hyperlink

I have a SharePoint list and it has a field Named "Type" and it contains two values 
1. SOP
2. RAM
here when user is adding an item and if he selects "SOP" in "type" field then a document link should be populated in that same window where a user should be able to open it and fill the document and close it (here the document should be saved as an attachment).

I cannot use any C# coding, all I have is Out of box features. 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use JavaScript.

Just add your code in the page. You didn't provide your level of skills for this language, so I don't know how much info you need....

But the idea is to add an action related to the dropdown box. Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { // = make sure the page/document is fully loaded
  // when we select a value for the dropdown box called "Type" then do some actions
  $('select[title="Type"]').on('change', function() {
    var val=$(this).val(); // get the selected value
    if (val === "SOP") alert("You have selected SOP") // take actions based on the value
  })
})
</script>
```

`$('select[title="Type"]')` should return you the dropdown box called "Type" (usually, in the form, we can use the title attribute to locate a field).

Comment: Firstly thanks for your response.. My skill level in jquery or Jscript is Low so can you please elaborate? where should I Add? and will the document will be saved as an attachment ?

Comment: Open the form files (NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx) in Sharepoint Designer ("Edit File in Advanced Mode"). Find `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` and just after it add the code above. After that you need to dig on Google to learn more about JavaScript because I cannot do everything for you...